# Anomaly Detection in a set of points

Tags: data-mining, computational-statistics

I have a set of points in a matrix of size 100 x 100(total 10000 points). I know that there are roughly 500 anomaly points in it. There is a corresponding truth file which contains the true anomalous points which is not available while building the algorithm. The goal is to  maximize the F-measure of the anomalies returned. How do I approach this problem?

[The dataset of all points](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2387762/anomaly.dat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the outliers you could use an outlier detection algorithm like [Local Outlier Factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor). This algorithm computes a score for each data point, so that you could treat the 500 objects with the highest score as an outlier.